# Install Virtualbox Headless on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I want to install Virtualbox on my Ubuntu 19.04 server, and fill its plenty of RAM with Virtual Machines to experiment with over SSH or via RDP.

Unfortunately, I'm having a hard time installing Virtualbox so I can use it in headless mode. Running the official deb package from the website tries to pull in several dependencies (libqt, libsdl) and X11, which I don't want on my server.

If I don't install these packages, apt stays in a "broken" state, because there are unmet dependencies.

What's the best way to do this cleanly?

Comment: Virtual box has a `--type headless` option. Read more here https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html.

Comment: I know that Virtualbox has a headless mode, my question is about how to get it installed without pulling in X11 and graphics-related libs.